# UI freezes while reading data on serial port

Tags: wpf, serial-port

I am developing a WPF application which will read data on serial port, parse it and will display it on the UI.

I have to use serial port Buad rate  - 115200, data bits - 8, Stop bit - 1.

I am sending 10000 bytes per second on the serial port which will be read by my WPF application.

But, Here I am facing issue with the UI. As I starts reading the COM port my UI freezes. It doesn't allow anyone to do anything. As per my investigation it is due to the high speed of data.

1. I am reading com port on different thread and UI is running on different thread.
2. The data transmission between threads are done using a common circular buffer.
3. I do have used BeginInvoke methods to update UI fields so function gets return immediately.
4. I do have used lock mechanism while accessing the circular buffer in both the threads.

Is there any way to handle this situation? I have read that lot of people facing same kind of issue. What is the solution using which such issue can be resolve.

Thanks,
Vishal N

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: Are you sure that you are on different threads? Does your port read finish? Post some code please.

Comment: Step 3 is the problem, you are doing it too often.  The UI cannot keep up.  Just do it *much* less often, you only need to keep human eyes busy.  They can't see anything that updates faster than 20 times per second.  Buffer the received data until you get the full response.  And minimize the amount of info you dump on the UI.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you have either set up your `Thread` object(s) incorrectly, or you are passing feedback back to the UI too often.

If you are not comfortable about working with `Thread` objects directly, perhaps the `BackgroundWorker` class might help you. Check out the [BackgroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) page at MSDN.